# Javascript Not a number

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently doing a computer science project, where I am trying to create a calculator for a points system, the type of transport provides a multiplier where  the distance is used to calculate it. At first I had the the distance at a set number of 10, however when I tried to change it to where the user inputs a distance, the number calculated is not considered a number. My code is below:

```js
var Companies = [
  [1, "Barclays", 50, 100],
  [2, "Google", 20, 40],
  [3, "Microsoft", 80, 160]
];
var Transport = [
  ["Car", 1.2],
  ["Bike", 1.5],
  ["Walk", 1.6],
  ["Public Transport", 1.3],
  ["Car Share", 1.4]
];


var Distance = 10;
var Carbo = 0;

function Carbo_Calculator() {
  var Transport_Chosen = document.getElementById("Transport_Chosen").value;
  var Company_Chosen = document.getElementById("Company_Chosen").value;
  for (i = 0; i < Transport.length; i++) {
    if (Transport_Chosen == Transport[i][0]) {
      Carbo = Distance * Transport[i][1];
      for (j = 0; j < Companies.length; j++) {
        if (Company_Chosen == Companies[j][1]) {
          Companies[j][3] = Companies[j][3] + Carbo;
          console.log(Companies);
        }
      }
      alert(Carbo);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Transport:</h1>
<select id="Transport_Chosen">
  <option>Transport...</option>
  <option value="Car"> Car </option>
  <option value="Bike"> Bike </option>
  <option value="Walk"> Walk </option>
  <option value="Public Transport"> Public Transport </option>
  <option value="Car Share"> Car Share </option>
</select>

<h1>Companies:</h1>
<select id="Company_Chosen">
  <option>Companies...</option>
  <option value="Barclays"> Barclays </option>
  <option value="Google"> Google </option>
  <option value="Microsoft"> Microsoft </option>
</select>

<h1>Distance</h1>
<input type="number" id="Distance" placeholder="Distance">

<button onclick="Carbo_Calculator()"> Go! </button>
```

Even though the distance is set to 10, when I change it to `Distance = document.getElementById("Distance).value;` and then try to run it, where the user inputs it, the alert says not a number, even though the data type input is a number.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse your data to numbers since the `.value` attribute returns a string, so when you enter 10 for example the `input.value` will return a string `"10"`.

You could use `Number()` or `parseInt()` like :

```
var Transport_Chosen = Number( document.getElementById("Transport_Chosen").value );
var Company_Chosen   = Number( document.getElementById("Company_Chosen").value );

//Or

var Transport_Chosen = parseInt( document.getElementById("Transport_Chosen").value );
var Company_Chosen   = parseInt( document.getElementById("Company_Chosen").value );
```

Comment: I've tried it and for some reason it doesn't work, the webpage literally doesn't respond, the transport chosen and company chose I don't think need to be changed because the whole code worked before when the value of var Distance = 10; Now when I change it to Distance = document.getElementById("Distance").value it states it is NaN, so then when I used your way of changing it to var Distance = parseInt/Number(document.getElementById("Distance").value); it does nothing, any ideas? @Zakaria

Answer (score 1):

from `isNAN` function we can identify variable is numeric or not.

If type cast is string `for ex- "100"` then we can parse it to number (integer or float)

```
parseInt() OR parseFloat()
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try now

Comment: I have changed the value of the variable distance from var Distance = 10; to var Distance = parseInt(document.getElementById("Distance").value); and now it still says it is not a number